# VB.NET, Framework 3.5 | Windows & ProgramFilesX86 Folder As String?

Tags: vb.net, frameworks, .net-3.5

With **NET Framework 4.5**, `GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows)`, the method `GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)` works.

With **NET Framework 3.5** it doesn't. I have to do that with the old Framework. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: What does "not works" actually mean?  ALWAYS be specific.

Comment: So, what you actually meant was that `SpecialFolder.Windows` and `SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86` don't exist in .NET 3.5 because, as the documentation says, they were added in .NET 4.0.  The documentation also states that the `Windows` item corresponds to a couple of specific environment variables, so you can get that path using those.  I would guess that there's a similar option for the 32-bit Program Files folder. People have needed that path before .NET 4.0 so there will almost certainly be examples of how they got it on the web already.

Answer (score 3):

Targeting `.Net Framework 3.5`, you can get all the Environmental variables with [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2). This method is there from `.Net 1.1` (and is still valid in `.Net 4.7.2`)

```
Dim dict As IDictionary = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

[`EnvironmentVariableTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.7.2) can be limited to `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` or `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` for a subset of values.

When you parse the returned Dictionary, you'll see that it contains two variables (among the others):

`ProgramFiles` and `ProgramFiles(x86)` ← No spaces

Their path can then be obtained with:

```
Dim ProgramFiles As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")

Dim ProgramFilesx86 As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)")
```

The returned values depend on both the OS and the Application bitness.
When a program targets `x86` in a `x64` machine, they both will return `...\Program Files (x86)`

In a `x86` machine, they both will return `...\Program Files`